# Error in installation of odoo in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, odoo

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 i want to install `odoo v9`.

I followed these steps:

> To install Odoo 9.0 on Debian-based distribution, execute the
>   following commands as root:
>
> ```
> wget -O - https://nightly.odoo.com/odoo.key | apt-key add -
> echo "deb http://nightly.odoo.com/9.0/nightly/deb/ ./" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
> apt-get update && apt-get install odoo
> ```

But it returns an error such as

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/odoo.postinst: 28: /var/lib/dpkg/info/odoo.postinst: update-python-modules: not found
dpkg: error processing package odoo (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 odoo
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: You're trying to run the *development build* of a *third-party* software on an *unreleased* version of Ubuntu. This is off topic here. Please file a bug report with the developers of that piece of software.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - I've seen you post a similar comment on many questions. I am in agreement that 16.04 hasn't been released yet and is therefore off-topic.... but let's be reasonable here! -  *It's coming out tomorrow!*

Comment: There's still the issue with the development build of a third-party software which is typically also off topic here. Also, Canonical may still move the release date for some reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

Those commands would fix the above issue as it works for me

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-support/python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
dpkg -i python-support_1.0.15_all.deb
apt install odoo
```

Source link https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/11785

Answer (score 0):

For Odoo 16 Features, you can Visit - https://www.browseinfo.in/blog/browseinfo-app-articles-3/post/odoo-v16-features-55

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).